# Issue with UTF-8 character in post URL using Octopress

Tags: url, utf-8, jekyll, octopress

I'm migrating my blog from wordpress and found an old post that google has indexed and seems to have a URL in the following form:

```
http://olddomain.com/old-post-title-%E2%80%93-part-2
```

You can see the %E2%80%93 in the URL, which apparently correspond to some kind of dash character (not your average '-') in UTF-8

In Jekyll, it seems that just adding `%E2%80%93` to the blogpost title doesn't work...

I actually added the '-' to my url by just appending it, and to my octopress slug...

When I run `rake preview` I get a 404 (by following the link in my `blog archives`)

`127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2013 16:17:53] "GET /blog/2010/12/old-post-title-%E2%80%93-part-2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - 0.0009`

Any ideas of what can I do to get this fixed?

Comment: I see it is an old post, but I am getting the same issue. Have you fixed it by any chance?